# SharedPreferences not getting stored between calls

Tags: flutter, dart

It seems that for some reason my `SharedPreferences` don't get stored properly.

```
    SharedPreferences p = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    p.setInt('____debug1', 1);

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) async {
        SharedPreferences p2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        print('____debug1: ${p2.getInt('____debug1')}' );
    });
```

results in

```
____debug1: null
```

while I was expecting it to print `1`.

What could be causing this? I'm using SharedPreferences 0.5.3+4 and Flutter Doctor says

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-SE)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3.4)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

**EDIT**

If I change the code to look like this

```
    SharedPreferences p = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await p.setString('____debug1', '6');
    print('____debug1 (1): ${p.getString('____debug1')}' );

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) async {
        SharedPreferences p2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        print('____debug1 (2): ${p2.getString('____debug1')}' );
    });
```

and update the value from `1`, `2`, `3` etc. on each execution, I get the following results:

```
____debug1 (1): 6
____debug1 (2): 5
```

so it seems that reading the value outside the `Future` works as expected, but when reading it 3 seconds later inside the `Future` I get a stale value...

**EDIT 2 - Minimal reproducible example**

1. Create a new Flutter app (the "Press-a-button-counter" will do).
2. Add the following code to `_MyHomePageState`:

---

```
@override
void initState() {
  initAsync();
}


initAsync() async {
  scheduleMicrotask(() async {
    SharedPreferences p = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  });

  String x = '1'; // <-- Change me between runs!

  SharedPreferences p = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await p.setString('x', x);
  print('x (1): ${p.getString('x')}' );

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) async {
    SharedPreferences p2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print('x (2): ${p2.getString('x')}' );
  });
}
```

3. Change the value of `x` between each run.

The result that I'm getting is

```
First run
    x (1): 1
    x (2): null

Second run
    x (1): 2
    x (2): 1

Third run
    x (1): 3
    x (2): 2

... etc ...
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is because I run your code and it is displaying `____debug1: 1`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Does it still work if you change the number to `2`? For me, it prints the old value of the last time the code was executed. So after I run it once it will display `1`, but the value was actually saved to preferences on the previous execution, not the current. Also see my added edit to the question - it works outside the `Future` but inside the `Future` I get the old value.

Comment: Did you try to use only p instead p2? (it should be the same, but something weird is happening)

Comment: @PabloBarrera Hmm I thought I tried it before and it didn't help, but now I tried again and it seems to work... but it's useless in my real scenario where I'm writing and reading to/from the settings in two different places of my code. And as you say, it shouldn't matter since `getInstance()` returns a singleton...

Comment: @MagnusW It works as expected, every time I change the value I see same value printed in `debug1` and `debug2`, can you create a minimal reproducible full code?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I tried recreating the problem in a brand new Flutter app, but I can't reproduce it there. However, in my original app it still behaves like this. Not sure what's causing it as the app is quite large and complex, but essentially I'm running this debug code in an `async` method called from `MyAppState.initState()`. Other models are initializing themselves and accessing `SharedPreferences` at this time as well, however none of them access the `____debug1` value, so it shouldn't matter? Could it be some kind of race condition in the singleton code in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: @MagnusW Looks like a race condition but according me to there shouldn't be any race condition with singleton code of `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I finally figured out a minimal reproducible example, see my edit. It seems to be caused by `scheduleMicroTask`, which in my real world code is being called by `notifyListeners()` from the `ScopedModel` class.

Comment: Yes, it now shows the issue, but may I know why do you need `scheduleMicrotask`, if you remove it, the code works just fine.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad The provided code is an extreme simplification of my real world code. I'm initializing a whole bunch of stuff, including some `ScopedModel`'s in `initState()`. The `ScopedModel` class has a `notifyListeners()` method to let listeners (including the UI) know that something has changed in the model. This is what calls `scheduleMicrotask()`. I might be able to tweak away some of the calls to `notifyListeners()`, but it would of course be more convenient if things work as expected in either case... or is this an expected behaviour with `SharedPreferences` and `scheduleMicrotask()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not about the shared preferences but the initialization of it's singleton

**The Problem**

Since the code is executed on the initState() the singleton of the shared preferences is null and need to be initialized. But calling SharedPreferences.getInstance() in the microtask and in the initAsync, both asynchronous calls enter in the if (_instance == null) due to how Dart handles microtasks and events queues ([Futures - Isolates - Event Loop](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures---isolates---event-loop/)), and the last who creates the instance will be the microtask, so the instance used in the initAsync to use setString won't update the memory cache of the shared preferences

Here is an example to understand the problem:

```
@override
void initState() {
  initAsync();
  super.initState();
}

initAsync() async {
  scheduleMicrotask(() async {
    print("microtask: START ");
    TestClass microtask = await TestClass.getInstance("microtask");
    print("microtask: FINISH (instance: ${microtask.hashCode})");
  });

  print("initAsync_1: START");
  TestClass initAsync_1 = await TestClass.getInstance("initAsync_1");
  print("initAsync_1: FINISH (instance: ${initAsync_1.hashCode})");

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) async {
    print("initAsync_2: START");
    TestClass initAsync_2 = await TestClass.getInstance("initAsync_2");
    print("initAsync_2: FINISH (instance: ${initAsync_2.hashCode})");
  });
}

class TestClass {
  static TestClass _instance;
  static Future<TestClass> getInstance(String call) async {
    if (_instance == null) {
      print("$call: without instance before");
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      _instance = TestClass();
      print("$call: without instance after");
    } else {
      print("$call: with instance");
    }
    return _instance;
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
initAsync_1: START
initAsync_1: without instance before
microtask: START 
microtask: without instance before
initAsync_1: without instance after
initAsync_1: FINISH (instance: 674207757)
microtask: without instance after
microtask: FINISH (instance: 1059788553)
initAsync_2: START
initAsync_2: with instance
initAsync_2: FINISH (instance: 1059788553)
```

**The Solution**

You could initialize the singleton before calling the scheduleMicrotask(), just by adding a getInstance() call before that

```
await TestClass.getInstance("init");
```

And this would be the output for this example

```
init: without instance before
init: without instance after
initAsync_1: START
initAsync_1: with instance
microtask: START 
microtask: with instance
initAsync_1: FINISH (instance: 797421450)
microtask: FINISH (instance: 797421450)
initAsync_2: START
initAsync_2: with instance
initAsync_2: FINISH (instance: 797421450)
```

Comment: I haven't had time to test this yet, but what you're saying makes sense. So basically the microtask is executing in a separate thread than the rest of the initState() code? And it's just down to bad timing that they both enter the singleton if statement before the other one has finished it? When I was looking at getInstance() earlier I kind of felt like they should have used a mutex or at the very least set _instance() to something <> null right at the beginning of the block. Or at least mentioned somewhere that it's not thread/microtask-safe (maybe they did but I just didn't see it?)

Comment: Dart is single thread but the way the microtasks and events are handled in queues made this happen. Here is a good article explaining how it works https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures---isolates---event-loop/

Comment: @PabloBarrera Good example, wish I could vote it more than once!